# Pure java adb client

Tags: java, android, adb

[ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) is split into a server part and a client part that talks to each other via a TCP protocol described more in detail [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/OVERVIEW.TXT).

Is there any pure java ADB client out there? This can be very usefull if you want to drive the Packet Manager or Activity Manager from a jUnit or TestNG test case for example.

We have the adb command line client binary on the major development platforms, but is there a pure Java implementaion of the adb client.

Comment: what advantages are you looking for exactly?

Comment: actually, I want to drive UiAutomator tests from a dev machine. But the usefullness of such a client library should have a much broader use. A pura java client is inherently cross plattform and just overall smoother to work with compared to the native command line tool adb.

Comment: i know what you mean, i have the exact same issue, though i'm using python. the protocol is described in: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/SERVICES.TXT but i found a few projects... looking for a pure java client lead me to your question here, so i guess the answer is:" not really" unless u'll do it yourself..

Comment: I actually created a small java project, but forgot to post an answer here. It's not possible however to send files as this was not described in a document but rather in code. My intention is to write the file syncing code and also create the SYNC.TXT file at the same time and then make a pull request to the AOSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a small java project called **jadb** available [here](https://github.com/vidstige/jadb) that implements <s>parts</s> most of what `adb` client does, including sending files. It requires the `adb` server running (the `adb` binary)

Comment: This sounds interesting. Under which licence have you released this (there doesn't seem to be any currently in the repository)?

Comment: @Bruno I'm releasing it under the Apache 2.0 License. This is also the license the Android Open Source Project is released under. The jadb project is based on the AOSP so this makes sense. Also this license is usually best for companies and other Open Source projects. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your lib is using sockets to connect to the `adb` server which is a part of the same `adb` binary. So until you reimplement the server part as well (including handling of `USB` transport) your code would still require native `adb`

Comment: @AlexP. fair enough. I've updated the answer to clarify the server is in the same binary.