# Java library for Android ADB

Tags: java, android, adb

What library would you suggest for doing ADB related tasks from Java. I have a basic prototype where I fork the adb process and take the output from the process. Is there a better way for doing it via a library?. I also took a look at the ddmlib library provided by android, but seems like it is not actively developed. Is there a better library or is ddmlib up for the job ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your use case, but ddmlib should be enough. If nothing else it can run shell commands on the device, which is better than forking the adb process.

Also see if chimpchat suits your needs, it's the library that MonkeyRunner uses. It's more geared towards UI interaction if that suits you better.

Answer (score 6):

This repository maybe will give you some help:

https://github.com/vidstige/jadb

Answered here:[Pure java adb client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861234/pure-java-adb-client)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have already looked at it. Seems to be not actively developed.

Comment: Oh,yes.it's not very active.If you have interest in this,you can implement this by yourself,and then it will be very popular.I think your idea will be a good tool.

Comment: @jvc Author of jadb here. :-) There is some activity, a pr every to every other month. It's pretty stable, tested, and has most features. I try to monitor bugs, etc closely. Is there any specific feature you are missing?